# Clean shutdown of external application in Eclipse?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, application-shutdown

Eclipse has `External Tools` capability, which allows to run some external program. For example I can run MySQL server with a command

```
MYPATH\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld.exe --verbose --console
```

Now, how to stop this server? I can define separate starter, but it is not cool

```
MYPATH\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin\mysqladmin.exe" shutdown --user=root --password=pwd
```

since (1) contains explicit password and (2) uses separate starter.

What happen if I terminate program with red square button? Will it stop gracefully? MySQL can be stopped by `Ctrl-C` in console, but Eclipse console ignores this keystroke.

Can I define some action on stopping external program in Eclipse?